# Force Echo 2 to Mono Output

Tags: amazon-echo

My Echo (2nd Gen) is paired with a Bluetooth receiver which, in turn, feeds that signal to a 70 volt Mono amp that services the entire house, one speaker per room. Listening to the music, it sounds very much like I am getting only the Left or Right channel of a stereo signal rather both channels in a mono signal.

I see no control in the App to configure this sound output. I assume Mono is the default setting. Is it possible that I am getting one channel or the other?  If so, how do I correct this?

Comment: Looks like your Bluetooth receiver cannot give both channels to your AMP. This can happen due to audio jack type. Because you need to have a Stereo to Mono convert for this to resolve. Bluetooth receiver giving both channels to Mono AMP, but amp can only take one part fro stereo jack.

Comment: Lahiru, I'm running a "stereo to mono" cable from the Bluetooth to the amp, but given your analysis, I will replace it with a new one and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Confirmed. Bad cable. Thanks Lahiru for knocking on my head a bit. I should have figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

To sum left and right channels into a mono input a series resistor on each of the stereo channels is required.